# Is the universe getting hotter? Brighter?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, space-expansion, universe, fusion

Due to their fusion processes every star is radiating massive amounts of photons and (to a lesser extent) neutrinos. Are all of these getting absorbed in matter over time, warming it, or is the total number of photons/neutrinos in the universe increasing over time? Am I missing a third option?

Comment: zero,
Stephan Hawking says : If you want to make a big pit, you're also making a big hill

Comment: Maybe the opposite, it is getting dimmer? the energy per photon is decreasing per the expansion of the universe.

Comment: I was considering that, but that would just change the energy per photon. The total number of photons would still continually rise.

Comment: You might like to consider the energy in those stellar photons vs the energy in the CMB photons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes WaveInPlace photons will always be generated until the last stars burn out. So will neutrinos as a side product. But the overall mass-energy density of the universe per fixed metric volume will drop, like the temperature, via "dark energy" and wavelength expansion. So the SM says, anyway.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).